# Transfer data before being incremented by loop

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to get ID to transfer when the button is clicked both ID and button is within the loop(so that they appear in a single row) but when I click the button it only transfers the last ID in the table...

```
    <%
int ID = 0;
int userID =0;
String deleteRow = "delete_Row.jsp";
String myPage = "profile.jsp";  
while (rs.next()) {
ID ++; 
%>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="success">
                <td><%=ID%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(6)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(7)%></td>

                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="window.location='<%= myPage %>';">Check Details</button></td>           
                <td><button href="delete_Row.jsp?userID=<%ID%>"type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="window.location='<%=deleteRow%>';">Remove</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

<% } %> `
```

Comment: So, what would be the expected behaviour?

Comment: I'd be able to use ID to display that table row alone by transferring its value to another jsp page, but because of the loop incrementing ID only the last row is being transferred

Answer (score 0):

I spot two errors in your program:

- The most important: `<button>` has no `href` attribute. I suggest you change it by:

  `<A href="delete_Row.jsp?userID=<%ID%>">Remove</A>`
- The less important: The `<tbody>` should be defined *outside* the loop.